# when i import numpy and pandas in jupyter it gives error same in spider but in spider works after starting new kernel

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook

When I import numpy and pandas in jupyter it gives error same in spider but in spider works after starting new kernel.

```
import numpy as np
```

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0aa0b027fcb6> in <module>
----> 1 import numpy as np

~\numpy.py in <module>
      1 from numpy import*
      2 
----> 3 arr = array([1,2,3,4])

NameError: name 'array' is not defined
```

Comment: by mistake np is written on top.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. It was a very bad mistake my c files have program numpy.py so while importing numpy python was accessing that file not the numpy module. So i deleted that and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

this is showing "NameError" which is due to the 
    arr=array([1,2,3,4])
you should try something like this 
    arr=np.array([1,2,3,4])

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr=np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: I am not creating anything i just importing numpy it gives error, !!

Comment: Try to uninstall numpy and install it with pip like this: 'pip uninstall numpy' and 'pip install numpy' and write 'import numpy as np'

Comment: I am using anaconda environment and i had unistalled and installed again, every thing works fine except pandas and numpy

Answer (score 0):

As you are using numpy as np, to create an array the following syntax is needed:
arr=np.array([1,2,3])

Comment: I am not creating anything i just importing numpy it gives error, !!